# Understanding line numbers reported when using eval

Tags: shell-script, debugging

Okay, so I'm stuck working with a shell script that needs to use `eval` (I know, I know, ultimate evil etc…) however I'm having difficulty debugging some of the line numbers being thrown out by errors.

For example:

```
script.sh: eval: line 315: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The line definitely doesn't correspond to line 315 in `script.sh` as that's entirely unrelated to the error. So I threw in random new-lines to figure out which line is originating the error, and as you'd expect it's a line with an `eval` statement.

However, when I output the code being passed into the `eval`, it doesn't even contain 200 lines, let alone 315+! So what's going on here? Is there a way to usefully use the line numbers being reported, are they somehow based on the position at which the `eval` statement is run or something? I don't seem to be able to see a pattern thus far.

If I could I'd replace all the `eval` statements, but unfortunately the code being passed is dynamically generated (not from user-input, don't worry!), and needs to be able to manipulate variables in the same scope as the rest of the script, which seems to preclude using `echo "$commands" | sh` or similar alternatives. I also have the issue of compatibility, and unfortunately as evil as it is `eval` is widely available.

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: yes, line numbers when using `eval` are random with `bash`, try to interpret the script with a compatible shell, `zsh` in `bash` emulation mode and ksh93 come to mind.

Comment: What if you execute your script with printing line numbers for all executed lines instead of just getting the line number where the error happened. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17805088/184968. It might give you an idea what is wrong with the script. So you run your script in this way: `PS4='$0.${LINENO}: ' bash -x script.sh`

Comment: Please show the lines of code that have `eval`.